# Is this a good way to query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to find the best way to design a mongodb schema that is processing friendly regarding values in another schema.

What I want is to process messages based on values in the user schema. So I want to e.g. process messages based on what gender the creator is. Though I have a hard time finding the best way to do it.

The current solution I see it to query every user if they are male, and then query the message schema based on those user ids. But the overhead of this will be quite extreme if the user count is high. And putting the messages as an embedded document in user-schema won't do since it will probably reach the 16mb limit.

User schema

```
User: {
    email: abc@abc.com,
    password: banana,
    gender: male,
    messages:[
        {messageId: 123},
    ]
}
```

Message schema

```
Message: {
    id: 123,
    text: "hi", 
}
```

Comment: Use a proper [index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/). Searching by a single parameter is really not a problem, even with millions of documents.

Comment: But the problem is that one gets multiple ids from user schema that one later will use to get message documents.  The complexity would be quite extreme. Though it's probably a bad idea to query that much for a processing task.